# Kernel Compiling error

Tags: android, compilation, kernel

whenever i try to compile the samsung stock 4.4.2 kernel i m getting this error

```
 CC    arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8930-display.o
arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8930-display.c: In function 'mipi_dsi2lvds_cdp_panel_power':
arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8930-display.c:577:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'msm_xo_get' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8930-display.c:577:26: error: 'MSM_XO_TCXO_A1' undeclared (first use in this function)
arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8930-display.c:577:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8930-display.c:663:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'msm_xo_mode_vote' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8930-display.c:663:31: error: 'MSM_XO_MODE_ON' undeclared (first use in this function)
arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8930-display.c:671:31: error: 'MSM_XO_MODE_OFF' undeclared (first use in this function)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8930-display.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/arm/mach-msm] Error 2 }
```

this is the lines the terminal pointed to in board-8930-display.c

1. rfa_clock = msm_xo_get (MSM_XO_TCXO_A1, id); /*create a handle for Aq buffer of XO*/
2. msm_xo_mode_vote(rfa_clock, MSM_XO_MODE_ON); /*Vote to turn ON the clock buffer*/

3.msm_xo_mode_vote(rfa_clock, MSM_XO_MODE_OFF); /*Vote to turn OFF the clock buffer*/

how can this be fixed ?

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet, please post the exact command(s) you used to kick off the kernel build. I suspect you either did not set the ARCH environment variable, or you are missing some necessary headers and/or files.